# Load all configuration that has a particular config dependency?

Tags: 8

I want to load all entity form display configuration that has a particular, DIRECT, config dependency. I feel like this is something that should be doable with an entity query but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: Reason for voting to close? This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. You need to use wildcards and pass an array of potential matching values.

```
$form_displays = \Drupal::entityQuery('entity_form_display')
  ->condition('dependencies.config.*', ['field.field.paragraph.call_to_action.field_cta_text'])
  ->execute();
```